# Tkinter: Scrollable Frame within a Notebook

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have written a class that basically manages a collection of Checkbuttons within a scrollable frame:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class SelectionList(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        vscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        vscrollbar.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.FALSE)
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                           yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set)
        canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)
        vscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

        canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        canvas.yview_moveto(0)

        self.__interior = ttk.Frame(canvas)
        self.__interior.pack()
        canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self.__interior, anchor=tk.NW)

    def add_item(self, item):
        cb = ttk.Checkbutton(self.__interior, text=str(item))
        cb.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=5, pady=2)
```

In most places this widget works the way I intended it to work. However when I add a SelectionList to a ttk.Notebook and then call the add_item method I get the following error, which I have not been able to figure out:

```
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!application.[...].!notebook.!selectionlist.!canvas.!frame"
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured it out while trying to create the example. Turns out that in a separate method I accidentally removed the canvas from the frame before trying to add an item.